# Segmentation Fault while replacing a character x86 NASM on Linux

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, stack

I'm getting a segmentation fault after writing `mov [gtt+4], byte '>'` where my variable is defined as `gtt: db "I'm ! than 10"`.
I feel like it might be an error when assembling the program.
I'm using the commands: `nasm -f elf file.asm -o file.o`, `ld -m elf_i386 file.o -o file`
I have tried to use elf32 rather than elf but it doesn't make a difference.
The purpose of my program is to loop 2 times, multiplying whatever is in ebx by 2 each time. Afterwards, it will compare if ecx > 10 and displaying the corresponding string. I'm trying to get it to replace the "!" with either "<" or ">".

I'm using Ubuntu, and I'm working in x86 assembly.
Here is my full code snippet:

```
section .data:
    starti: db "Starting value: 1", 0x0a
    startil equ $-starti

    gtt: db "I'm > than 10!", 0x0a
    gttml equ $-gtt 

section .text:
_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, starti
    mov edx, startil
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 1  ; Start value!  
    mov ecx, 2  ; Number of iterations  


label:
    add ebx, ebx    ; Add 2*ebx
    dec ecx     ; ecx -= 1
    cmp ecx, 0  ; If ecx > 0, loop again
    jg label
    
    cmp ebx, 10 ; If cbx > 10, jump to gtt-g
    jg gttg

    mov [gtt+4], byte '<'
    mov eax, 4  ; If cbx < 10, output <
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, gtt
    mov edx, gttml
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1  ; Exit gracefully
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
    
gttg: 
    mov [gtt+4], byte '>'
    mov eax, 4  ; Display gtt
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, gtt
    mov edx, gttml
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax, 1  ; Exit gracefully
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

**Fix**
Thanks to Jester for this, "you must not use colons after section names, they are not labels. As it is, the colon is included in the name and hence the assembler doesn't recognize them as standard sections and doesn't apply the expected attributes meaning your data is read only. TL;DR: use section .data and section .text without a trailing".

Comment: 1/ I've never heard of `nsam`, perhaps you mean `nasm` :-) 2/ Your "full" code snippet seems to be missing the `var` variable and any manipulation of it. Suggest you post the *actual* code, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: You must not use colons after section names, they are not labels. As it is, the colon is included in the name and hence the assembler doesn't recognize them as standard sections and doesn't apply the expected attributes meaning your data is read only. TL;DR: use `section .data` and `section .text` without a trailing `:`.

Comment: @paxdiablo I updated it to write nasm (I swear my brain wants to keep writing nsam), and I've changed it from var to gtt. I was originally writing an example for it and forgot to change it. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @Jester Ah, I see. Fixed it and now it works. Thanks!